# host hangs after cat /dev/null > bigfile.log

Tags: text-processing, performance, io

I found a big log file(2.7 TB) on my disk, so I decided to empty it with the following command:

```
cat /dev/null > bigfile.log
```

After I executed this cmd, I lost my ssh connection. When I logged in via ssh again, the host hung. Each cmd output seemed lagging 1-2 seconds.

Even when I found out the defunct processes by below command. I even couldn't kill the processes because kill -9 $pid didn't work.

```
lsof | grep bigfile.log
```

Afterall, the host recovered by itself in almost 1 hour. During this period, the ioutil was very high.

It's a common way I use to empty text file. I wonder why it's not ok with big log file?

```
cat /dev/null > file.log
```

By the way, my environment is Linux Centos 6.3. Much thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a bug. This command should finish instantly. CentOS 6.3 has long been unsupported and it's not even the latest version of CentOS 6.

Comment: You also have a few other ways to empty the file that don't rely on `cat`. You can use `: > bigfile.log` or `truncate -s 0 bigfile.log`. The first is easy to use but the second, especially in scripts, gives a very big hint of the intent.